# hacer un gráfico con varias densidades de pronóstico

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tuve que estimar la densidad de pronóstico de una variable para diferentes horizontes de tiempo. tengo una matriz como la siguiente:

```
       h1       h2       h3       h4       h5
[1,] 3036.383 2872.860 2865.525 2971.019 2962.292
[2,] 3028.684 3014.297 2862.230 2842.563 2912.471
[3,] 2892.847 2928.340 2884.977 2862.875 2897.116
[4,] 2948.378 3043.170 2956.783 3028.778 2977.521
[5,] 3050.952 2893.631 2848.619 2934.641 2925.770
```

Cada Columna representa la densidad de pronóstico de la misma variable, solo que son pronósticos para diferentes momentos del tiempo. y quisiera realizar un gráfico como el siguiente:

[image: ejemplo]

No se si exista algún tutorial para hacerlo, que me puedan recomendar o si tienen una solución simple. Además sería mejor sí el gráfico es en scatterplot, no en linea.

Gracias

si miren:

```
#Librerias
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)

#Datos
grafico<-tribble(
~h1,~h2,~h3,~h4,~h5,
3036.383,2872.860,2865.525,2971.019,2962.292
,3028.684,3014.297,2862.230,2842.563,2912.471
,2892.847,2928.340,2884.977,2862.875,2897.116
,2948.378,3043.170,2956.783,3028.778,2977.521
,3050.952,2893.631,2848.619,2934.641,2925.770)

#Trasformamos los datos
grafico<-gather(grafico,tiempo,densidad,1:5)
grafico$tiempo<-as.numeric(stringr::str_replace_all(grafico$tiempo,"h",""))


 ggplot(grafico,aes(x=factor(tiempo),y=densidad,color=densidad))
   +geom_violin(aes(fill=tiempo),trim=F,scale="area")+
    scale_x_discrete(name="tiempo",limits=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13))
     +scale_fill_gradient(low="grey",high="grey1")
```

y logré hacer esta gráfica:

[image: gráfica]

Esto es lo que estoy buscando, ahora el problema que tengo en que el degradado de los colores primero se de dentro de cada violín y segundo, que el degradado sea conforme a la concentración, osea que donde el violín es gordo, sea más negro y donde el violín sea más estrecho el color se difumine.

Comment: Hola, has intentado algún código para lograr la gráfica? Este tutorial https://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rgraphics/Rgraphics.html te puede ayudar

Comment: ya puse el código y la gráfica como la que intento obtener

Comment: Logre replicar tu gráfica pero no más

Comment: Ya se cual sería una solución al problema, debería tener una tabla de frecuencias, con lo que lograría poner los colores como quiero hacerlo, pero no sabría como lograr  poner esos datos de frecuencia dentro del violin y dentro de los datos